# How to edit colliders in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I can edit colliders by holding down the shift key. But when i add a second collider, the shift key always selects the first one. And there is no "Edit Collider" button in the editor (Win/4.5.4f1). I'm testing it with two EdgeColliders2D.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for gamedev

Comment: @syloc Are you adding both colliders on a single GameObject?